# ERROR 1064 (42000): MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, trigger

Tengo que crear el trigger que deje en la imagen pero despues del else me manda el error 1064

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE TRIGGER ELIMINARCATEGORIAS BEFORE DELETE ON libro
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
SET @idLibro=(Select idLibro From libroCategoria where idLibro=OLD.idLibro); 
if(@idLibro>=1 OR @idLibro IS NOT NULL) THEN 
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT='No puede eliminar Datos porque esta relacionada la categoria'; 
ELSE 
DELETE FROM libroCategoria SET idLibro=0; WHERE libroCategoria.idLibro=OLD.idLibroCategoria; 
END//
END//
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar, tienes un error en el `DELETE` dentro del que introduces un `SET`, y también te falta un `END IF`.

En segundo, no estás utilizando las tablas adecuadas. Por el código que facilitas, tu base de datos parece tener esta estructura:

```
CREATE TABLE libro(
  idLibro int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  libro varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE categoria(
  idCategoria int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  categoria varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE libroCategoria(
  idLibroCategoria int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idLibro int,
  idCategoria int
  );
INSERT INTO libro (libro) VALUES
  ('Ilíada'),('Odisea'),('Cien años de soledad');
INSERT INTO categoria (categoria) VALUES
  ('Antigua Grecia'),('Novela'),('Comedia');
INSERT INTO libroCategoria (idLibro, idCategoria) VALUES
  (1,1),(2,1),(3,2);
```

Por lo que el disparador debería actuar sobre la tabla `categoria` en vez de sobre `libro`, tal que así:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_delete_categoria
  BEFORE DELETE ON categoria
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    DECLARE n int;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO n FROM libroCategoria
      WHERE OLD.idCategoria=libroCategoria.idCategoria;
    IF n>0 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT='No puede eliminar Datos porque esta relacionada la categoria';
    END IF;
  END;
```

Las instrucciones de comprobación serían:

```
DELETE FROM categoria
  WHERE idCategoria=3;
```

Que eliminaría la categoría `Comedia`, y:

```
DELETE FROM categoria
  WHERE idCategoria=1;
```

Que lanzaría el mensaje de error, impidiendo la eliminación de `Antigua Grecia`.

Y, ya por último, el enunciado resulta un tanto confuso, pues te anima a eliminar registros de una categoría que no contiene registros, precisamente por eso el disparador permite eliminarla. A no ser que se refiera al registro de la categoría en sí mismo, para lo que no hay que hacer nada, pues el disparador permite que se ejecute el `DELETE` simplemente no interviniendo.

Espero que fuera lo que buscabas. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios, evita usar imágenes si es mejor el texto y dale formato al código para que resulte más legible con Ctrl+k.